# How to change color of PyQt5 progress bar chunk without affecting the animation of QProgressBar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, progress-bar

I was working with PyQt5 progressbar. I made a simple UI for Progressbar testing. I tried to change the attributes of progressbar. Everything is alright, but when I tried to change the color of progress bar, **the flashing vanishes**.

Sample:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(266, 108)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(266, 108))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(266, 108))
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Form)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 141, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 89)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 20, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.cvalue)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 60, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.ccolor)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def ccolor(self):
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar::chunk "
                      "{"
                      "background-color: red;"
                      "}")

    def cvalue(self):
        val=self.lineEdit.text()
        val=int(val)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", val)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Change Value"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Change Color"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the sample gif:

[image]

Comment: This flashing is a part of default stylesheet animation. If you tries to update the stylesheet you need to write the stylesheet for animation yourself

Comment: No, the flashing is **not** part of the "stylesheet animation", as animations in Qt are provided by the QStyle, and Qt stylesheets do not support animations. This obviously means that you cannot write a stylesheet to display animations.